# copy files created or modified today with robocopy

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, copy, robocopy

I'm trying to create a batch file in Win7 that will copy any files that have been created or modified today and copy them to a destination with a similar directory structure. This is what I have so far:

```
set today="20180721"
robocopy "C:\temp\" "D:\backup\temp\" *.* /s /DCOPY:T /MINAGE:%today%
```

I know that /e copies empty directories and /xf excludes all files, but I'm not sure if that helps me. The code above seems to copy all files regardless of date, so I'm a little lost here.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear from the answer provided by @Squashman, instead of creating a variable, you should be able to use: `@RoboCopy "C:\Temp" "D:\Backup\Temp" /S /DCopy:T /MaxAge:1 >Nul`

Comment: `forfiles /P "C:\temp" /D -1 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE (2> nul md @relpath\.. & copy @relpath D:\backup\temp\@relpath)"`? (`forfiles` regards the date only so it really copies all files modified before today, while `robocopy` copies files modified before 24 hours)

Answer (score 2):

Assigning quotes to your variables is not a best practice and will cause problems with some commands if you try to quote the variable later on.  Regardless that was not your problem.  Your problem is you need to use the `/MAXAGE` option.  Reading the help file you should see this:

```
/MAXAGE:n : MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.`
```

So your code should be:

```
set "today=20180721"
robocopy "C:\temp\" "D:\backup\temp\" *.* /s /DCOPY:T /MAXAGE:%today%
```

Going to assume you thought the options were for INCLUDE.

Answer (score 1):

[`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)'s `/MINAGE`/`/MAXAGE` options regard the full date and time, so specifying something like `/MAXAGE:1` filters for files that have been modified within the last 24 hours.

If you want to process files which have been modified today only, hence regarding the date but not the time, you could use [`forfiles`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) and its '/D' option, like this:

```cmd
set "DEST=D:\backup\temp"
forfiles /P "C:\temp" /D +0 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE for %%Z in (@relpath) do @(2> nul md 0x22%DEST%\%%~Z\..0x22 & copy @relpath 0x22%DEST%\%%~Z0x22)"
```